# Save temporary data with CakePhp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, memcached, cakephp-2.0

I am looking for a solution in CakePhp, to store and read temporary datas :

I read some XML from others websites in order to display some news in my website, but on each page load, it does a call to the other xml websites.

Is there a way (memcached like) to save temp. data in CakePhp in order to store data for 1 hour and read  temp. data to display them in my webpages ; then 1 hour after update them (with cron) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CakePHP Caching](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#caching) seems what you'd want.

WHICH cache you use (Redis, Memcache...etc) would be up to you though.  Set your cache to last an hour, and you're all set.  (read more about cache on the link above).

If you're on CakePHP 2.5+, you can use the `remember` method [described here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#using-cache-to-store-common-query-results).

```
public function newest() {
    $model = $this;
    return Cache::remember('newest_posts', function() use ($model){
        // get your data from whatever source here, and return it
        return $model->getMyData();
    }, 'long');
}
```

Basically, this just checks to see if the cache key exists, and if not, runs some code in order to populate it again.

If you're below 2.5, you can do the same basic thing, but without the `remember`:

```
public function newest() {
    $result = Cache::read('newest_posts', 'long');
    if (!$result) {
        // get your data from whatever source here, and write it
        Cache::write('newest_posts', $this->getMyData(), 'long');
    }
    return $result;
}
```

If you don't have a cache engine installed or are aren't wanting to mess w/ your own server, there are companies that you can use for cache, and you can just set your cache settings to connect to them.  ObjectRocket (Redis) is the one I know offhand, but I'm sure there are plenty.

One of many awesome things about CakePHP, is that in this case, your code doesn't change regardless of Cache type/location/configuration you choose.

Comment: Quick question, will the cache flush itself or I need to configure a cron to do this ? At this time I use file caching.

Comment: @zeflex - you can set the length of the cache in the cache 'duration' setting:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-class

Comment: I agree, I did it, but does cakephp delete cache files itself without any cron setup ?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure w/ File Cache.  With Redis (as example), once the duration has passed, the key is automatically deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look by myself on files but as I overwrite old datas each N minutes, the files will not be deleted.

Comment: I have a one question related to it, suppose i am storing cache using file cache , but the cache is not used for like a month(neither i am storing or retrieving the data) and i had added the limit of cache to be only 1 week, would it be deleted automatically. Or cakephp deletes only after i atleast access the cache

Comment: @Abhishek sorrry for late late reply ... but the file will be deleted itself (automatically)

Comment: @Dave I am currently implementing Memcached instead of files caching (yay finally) , but I still have the same questions: does memcache delete itself the expired keys ? From what I can see in PHPMemcachedAdmin, it seems no. Does it means the old keys will be deleted only when the allocated memcached space will be full ...?